# Python copy.deepcopy() function not working properly

Tags: python, class, reference, copy, mutable

I have been playing with the deepcopy function and the copy function and I get the same issue with both of them. It is like the copy was a reference (or a pointer) instead of a proper copy. I am working with data records (classes) in Python, maybe it could be that.. I show you an example:

```
>>> import copy
>>> class player1:
...    age = 23
...    score = 1
>>> class player2:
...    age = 14
...    score = 2
>>> player3 = copy.deepcopy(player1)
```

I print the parameters.

```
>>> print player1.age, player1.score
23 1
>>> print player2.age, player2.score
14 2
>>> print player3.age, player3.score
23 1
```

Now I increment the score parameter in player1 data record.

```
>>> player1.score += 3
```

And I print the results again.

```
>>> print player1.age, player1.score
23 4
>>> print player2.age, player2.score
14 2
>>> print player3.age, player3.score
23 4
```

WHY HAS PLAYER 3 CHANGED?
I just incremented a parameter in player1, not player3. It is mutable instead of immutable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you are actually copying the class definition and not an instance of the class.

Another problem of the code is that the attributes `age` and `score` are part of the class and will be shared between all instances of that class. This is probably not what you intended.

What you probably want to do is:

```
import copy
class Player:
    def __init__(self, age, score):
        self.age = age
        self.score = score

player1 = Player(23, 1)
player2 = Player(14, 2)
player3 = copy.deepcopy(player1)

player1.age += 1

print "player1.age", player1.age
print "player3.age", player3.age
```

This gives you what you expect:

```
player1.age 24
player3.age 23
```

Comment: I disagree that the fact that age and score were class attributes is responsible for the observed behaviour; if player3 were really a different class, the OP wouldn't have had this problem.  I agree they *should* be instance attributes, but that's something different.

Comment: @DSM: Yes, agreed. I got obsessed with this at first, not even seeing that there were no class instances at all. I corrected this.

Answer (score 3):

This is working as designed.

In your sample code, you are copying class definitions, not object instances. From `copy` module manual page:

```
It does “copy” functions and classes (shallow and deeply), by returning the original object
unchanged
```

Hence:

```
player3 = copy.deepcopy(player1)
```

is the same as:

```
player3 = player1
```

However, if you copied instances of the classes, you would get the expected result:

```
player3 = copy.deepcopy(player1())
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) (emphasis mine):

> This version does not copy types like module, **class**, function, method,
>   nor stack trace, stack frame, nor file, socket, window, nor array, nor
>   any similar types.

You're trying to copy classes, and so:

```
>>> player3 = copy.deepcopy(player1)
>>> player1 is player3
True
```

but

```
>>> p1 = player1()
>>> p2 = player2()
>>> p3 = copy.deepcopy(p1)
>>> p1 is p3
False
```